# jQuery - Load content from another page - only once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this small script, which, when clicked on, will show the content from a page where I do a PHP query. My problem is, that if the user click multiply times, it will just load the content from the PHP page multiply times as well...

This is my jQuery code:

```
$('.notifications-load').on('click',function() {
        $('#notifications-holder').load("/?i=notifications");

    });
```

And my HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-bell notifications-load"><span class="notification">5</span></i>
<div id="notifications-holder"></div>
```

This is the PHP page (?i=notifications):

```
$n=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_notifications WHERE userid=0 OR userid=:userid");
$n->bindParam(":userid",$userdata['id']);
$n->execute();

$data=$n->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $value) {
 echo $value['text'];
}
```

If a user clicks example 3 times on `.notifications-load` , then the content from `/?i=notifications` will load 3 times into the `#notifications-holder` - how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, one character of difference will fix it:

```
$('.notifications-load').one('click',function() {
// Here -------------------^
    $('#notifications-holder').load("/?i=notifications");

});
```

jQuery's [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one) function hooks up a handler that it automatically unhooks the first time it's called.

If you have an aversion to using `one` (as some do, it's *really* easy to misread it as `on`), you have a couple of options:

1. You can create an alias for it:

   ```
   $.fn.onOnce = $.fn.one;
   ```
2. You can unhook the handler explicitly:

   ```
   $('.notifications-load').on('click.load',function() {
       $('#notifications-holder').load("/?i=notifications");
       $('.notifications-load').off('click.load');
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `$.one` you can check to see if `$('#notifications-holder')` already has a value. Something like:

```
$('.notifications-load').on('click',function() {
       var notification = $('#notifications-holder');
       if (!notification.html().trim().length) {
          notification.load("/?i=notifications");
       }
    });
```